# Show $1_A$ (dirac measure) is a random variable

Tags: probability

> Consider the sample space $\Omega := \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2$.
>
> The probability measure is given as $\mathbb{P}:=Uniform(\Omega)$.
>
> Let $A \subseteq \Omega$ and consider: $1_{A}:\Omega \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}, \quad w \mapsto \begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if} \; \omega \in A\\ 0 \quad \text{if} \; \omega \not \in A \end{cases}$
>
> Show that $1_A$ is a random variable and calculate $\mathbb{P}(1_A = 1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(1_A = 0)$.

I know that $X$ is a random variable if $X^{-1}(A') \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $A' \in \mathcal{A}$.

So, I think that we have $1_A^{-1}(1) = \Omega \in \mathcal{A}$. But what about $1_A^{-1}(0)$?

Further, I know that $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac {|A|}{|\Omega|}$.

Isn't $\mathbb {P}(1_A = 1)$ always just $1$?

Comment: You do not seem to know much about $A$ except that it is a subset of $\Omega$.  But, assuming $\mathcal{A}$ is the powerset of $\Omega$, you can say $1_A^{-1}(1) = A \in \mathcal{A}$  and $1_A^{-1}(0) = A^c \in \mathcal{A}$,

Comment: @Henry Ah, that is true. I assume $\mathcal{A} = P(\Omega)$ since it's just the usual throw a dice twice experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the probability distribution is uniform on a finite sample space, it implies that all subsets of the sample space are events and therefore every function out of the space is a random variable.

In general, it is true that $\mathbb P(1_A=1)=\mathbb P(A)$ which (as you already wrote) equals $|A|/|\Omega|$ in the case of a uniform distribution on a finite space.

So now let me convince you why $\mathbb P(1_A=1)=\mathbb P(A)$, since you seem to have had all the other pieces in place already. Remember that $1_A$ is a function of the sample space, we should be pedantic and write it as $1_A(\omega)$. Then, the event $\{\omega\in\Omega\colon 1_A(\omega)=1\}$ is (by definition) equal to the set of all $\omega\in\Omega$ for which $\omega\in A$ - or phrased more simply,
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega\colon 1_A(\omega)=1\}=A.
$$
This is why $\mathbb P(1_A=1)=\mathbb P(A)$.